# change ElastiCache node DNS record in cloud formation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53, amazon-elasticache

I need to create CNAME record for ElastiCache Cluster. However, I build redis cluster and there is only one node. As far as I found there is no 
ConfigurationEndpoint.Address for redis cluster. Is there any chance to change DNS name for node in cluster and how to do it?

Currently template looks like:

```
  "ElastiCahceDNSRecord" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "HostedZoneName" : "example.com.",
    "Comment" : "Targered to ElastiCache",
    "RecordSets" : [{
    "Name" : "elche01.example.com.",
    "Type" : "CNAME",
    "TTL" : "300",
    "ResourceRecords" :  [
        {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [ "myelasticache", "ConfigurationEndpoint.Address" ]
        }
    ]

    }]

  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `ConfigurationEndpoint.Address` is only supported for Memcached clusters, not for Redis. Please see [this relevant discussion](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=492354) in the AWS forums.

Also, the [AWS Auto Discovery docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/AutoDiscovery.html) (still) state:

> Note
>
> Auto Discovery is only available for cache clusters running the
>   Memcached engine. Redis cache clusters are single node clusters, thus
>   there is no need to identify and track all the nodes in a Redis
>   cluster.

Looks like your 'best' solution is to query the individual endpoint(s) in us, in order to determine the addresses to connect to, using `AWS::CloudFormation::Init` as is suggested on the AWS forums thread.

UPDATE

As [@slimdrive](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1666140/slimdrive) pointed out below, this IS now possible, through the `AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster`. Please read further below for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is possible solution however now sure if it worth it =)

Comment: @Kate yeah, I know, it's not great, but that is where things stand now... so, i guess there's no better solution at the moment.. Would you mind marking this as accepted ?

Comment: Not sure when AWS added this ability but you can get the `RedisEndpoint.Address` from the `AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster` see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46777048/1666140

Answer (score 6):

For folks coming to this page for a solution. There is now a way to get the Redis endpoint directly from within the CFN.

There is now the ability to get the `RedisEndpoint.Address` from the `AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster` or `PrimaryEndPoint.Address` from the  `AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup`

Per the documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticache-cache-cluster.html):

> RedisEndpoint.Address - The DNS address of the configuration endpoint for the Redis cache cluster.
>
> RedisEndpoint.Port - The port number of the configuration endpoint for the Redis cache cluster.

or

Per the documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html):

> PrimaryEndPoint.Address -
>   The DNS address of the primary read-write cache node.
>
> PrimaryEndPoint.Port -
>   The number of the port that the primary read-write cache engine is listening on.

An example CFN (other bits not included):

```
Resources:
  DnsRedis:
    Type: 'AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup'
    Properties:
      HostedZoneName: 'a.hosted.zone.name.'
      RecordSets:
        - Name: 'a.record.set.name'
          Type: CNAME
          TTL: '300'
          ResourceRecords:
            - !GetAtt
              - RedisCacheCluster
              - RedisEndpoint.Address  
    DependsOn: RedisCacheCluster

  RedisCacheCluster:
    Type: 'AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster'
    Properties:
      ClusterName: cluster-name-redis
      AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: 'true'
      AZMode: single-az
      CacheNodeType: cache.t2.small
      Engine: redis
      EngineVersion: 3.2.4
      NumCacheNodes: 1
      CacheSubnetGroupName: !Ref ElastiCacheSubnetGroupId
      VpcSecurityGroupIds:
        - !GetAtt
          - elasticacheSecGrp
          - GroupId
```

Comment: I was seeing other sources that said to use the `RedisEndpoint` attribute (which is only for a non-clustered version), and others said not to use that, use the `ConfigurationEndpoint` attribute.  Thanks for this.  If you have a redis cluster (Type = `AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup`), use the `PrimaryEndPoint` attribute's `Address` and `Port` property values..

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `PrimaryEndPoint.Address` instead of `ConfigurationEndpoint.Address` in the template provided to get the DNS address of the primary read-write cache node as documented on the [`AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup` page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-replicationgroup.html#d0e68542).

Comment: It's actually ConfigurationEnd*P*oint. Note capital P.

Answer (score 0):

This can be extremely confusing-- depending on what you're trying to do, you use either `ConfigurationEndpoint` or `PrimaryEndpoint`... I'm adding my findings here as this was one of the first posts I found when trying to search.  I'll also detail some other issues I've had with ElastiCache redis engine setup with CloudFormation.  I was trying to set up a CloudFormation type of `AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup`

Let me preface this with the fact that I had previously set up a clustered instance of redis ElastiCache using a t2.micro build type with no problems.  In fact, I received an error from the `node-redis` npm package saying that clusters weren't supported, so I also implemented the `redis-clustr` wrapper around that.  Anyway, all that was working fine.

We then moved forward with trying to create a CloudFormation template for this, and I ran into all sorts of limitations that the aws console UI must be hiding from people. In chronological order of how I ran into the problems, here were my struggles:

- `t2.micro instances are not supported with auto-failover.` So I set `AutomaticFailoverEnabled` to `false`.

  > Fix: t2.micro instances actually can use auto-failover.  Use the Parameter Group that has clustered mode enabled. The default one for me was `default.redis3.2.cluster.on` (I used version 3.2.6, as this is the most current that supports encryption at rest and in transit).  The parameter group can not be changed after the instance is created, so don't forget this part.
- We received an error from the `redis-clustr`/`node-redis` package: `this instance has cluster support disabled`.

  > (This is how I found the parameter group needed the value on)
- We received an error in the CF template that cluster mode can not be used if auto failure is off

  > This is what made me try using a t2.micro instance again, since I knew I had auto-failover turned on in my other instance and was using a t2.micro instance. Sure enough, this combination does work together.
- I had outputs to the stack and creation of parameters in the Parameter Store of the connection url and port. This failed with `x` attribute/property does not exist on the ReplicationGroup.

  > Fix: It turns out that if cluster mode is disabled (using parameter group `default.redis3.2`, for example), you must use the `PrimaryEndPoint.Address` and `PrimaryEndPoint.Port` values.  If cluster mode is enabled, use `ConfigurationEndPoint.Address` and `ConfigurationEndPoint.Port`.  I had tried using the `RedisEndpoint.Address` and `RedisEndpoint.Port` with no luck, though this may work with a single redis node with no replica (I also could have had the casing wrong-- see the note below).

**NOTE**
Also, a major issue affected me is the casing: The `P` in `EndPoint` must be capitalized in the `PrimaryEndPoint` and `ConfigurationEndPoint` variations if you are creating a `AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup`, but the `p` is lower case if you are creating a `AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster`:  `RedisEndpoint`, `ConfigurationEndpoint`.  I'm not sure why there's a discrepancy there, but it may be the cause of some problems.

[Link to AWS docs for `GetAtt`, which lists available attributes for different CloudFormation resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html)